# Scalatest test passing but not actually working

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

This is my scalatest file which tests savedat method.savedat enters an Employeeentry object in my table and returns number of rows saved which is 1 in my case:

```
class databasetest extends FlatSpec  { 
    "this" should "save a row in table" in new App{
        DB.withSession{ implicit session : Session => 
            Employee.savedat(EmployeeEntry(1,"james","bhagat","ghgas"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your problem is?

You are not putting any assertions in the test, it will always pass(assuming no exceptions happen)! A more meaningful test would be to read from the db afterwards and check that the Employee data are actually there. If that also fails, then you can post here the code of your savedat method and we can maybe help debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
class databasetest extends Specification {

"this" should {

  // val appWithMemoryDatabase = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase("test"))

     "test savedat" in new WithApplication {


         DB.withSession{

             implicit session :Session => 

             Employee.savedat(EmployeeEntry(45,"ketan","bhagat","ghgas")) must be equalTo (1)

         }


     }
```

The error was Play frequently requires a running Application as context which WithApplication object provides.